# How to make Controller parameters in Nest JS?

Tags: sql-server, rest, nestjs

Service Code:

```
        async breakStart(EmpId: string, BTTitle:string,Reas:string): Promise<any> {
            var ipadd='100.000.000.000';
            var time1='15:00';
            /*var EmpId=2;
            var BTTitle='Prayer';
            var Reas='Prayer';*/
            var data = await this.sequelize.query(
                'Exec API_Insert_Break_Start :EmployeeId, :BreakTypeTitle, :StartAtTime, :BreakInIP, :Reason',
              {
                replacements: { 
                    EmployeeId: EmpId,
                    BreakTypeTitle:BTTitle,
                    StartAtTime:time1,
                    BreakInIP:ipadd,
                    Reason:Reas},
                type: sequelize.QueryTypes.INSERT
              });
            //  return data;
        }
```

Controller Code:

```
  @Roles(Role.User)
  @UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard, RolesGuard)
  @Post('breakstart')
  async breakstart(@Request() reqbreakstart,@Param() params ) {
     var responsebreakstart;
    try {
      var databreakstart = await this.attendanceBreaksService.breakStart(params.EmpId, params.BTTitle,params.Reas);
      responsebreakstart = ResponseSuccess(databreakstart);
    } catch (e) {
      responsebreakstart = ResponseError(e.toString());
    }
    return responsebreakstart;

  }
```

The problem is that if i insert values (EmpId, BTTitle, Reas) in the Service then the code runs and inserts the values in the database. The actual problem is with the controller. I have tried using parameters through different methods but no use. Somehow the parameters i give in postman, aren't recieved by the controller. After running the code, Postman gives a 500 error and VS Code shows:

> Error: Named parameter ":EmployeeId" has no value in the given object.

Please have a look and tell where is the problem in my code. Thank you.

Comment: `@Param`s are for values passed through route parameters. It seems like you'd want to define a DTO (Data Transfer Object) class and retrieve it using `@Body()` as per the [Request payloads](https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers#request-payloads) examples.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I do want to use route parameters because I am using "Params" table in Postman, to give these parameters. These parameters are inserted in the URL in Postman and then sent. I will try your method too. Thanks.